# Magento2: Setup Script not loaded

Tags: magento2, module, setup-script, upgrade-script, installdata

I've been banging my head for a few hours now. I have setup a small Magento 2 module. It is enabled everything is working except the Setup scripts never run. Actually from my diagnosis right now, they aren't even required in the setup:upgrade process.

If it could be of any help here are the module configuration files:

registration.php:

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Wizbusiness_CustomerSubscriptions',
    __DIR__
);
```

etc/module.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
                <module name="Wizbusiness_CustomerSubscriptions" setup_version="0.0.9" />
</config>
```

Setup/InstallData.php:

```
<?php
namespace Wizbusiness\CustomerSubscriptions\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Module\Setup\Migration;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $setup->startSetup();

        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        /** @var CustomerSetup $customerSetup */
        $customerSetup->addAttribute(
            Customer::ENTITY,
            'subscribedtags',
            [
                'type' => 'text',
                'input' => 'multiselect',
                'backend' => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Backend\ArrayBackend',
                'global' => \Magento\Catalog\Model\Resource\Eav\Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
                'label' => 'Subscribed Tags',
                'required' => 0,
                'system' => 0, // <-- important, otherwise values aren't saved.
                               // @see Magento\Customer\Model\Metadata\CustomerMetadata::getCustomAttributesMetadata()
                'position' => 100,
                'filterable' => true,
                'option' => [ 'values' => ['Test', 'Test2', 'Test3' ] ]
            ]
        );

        $used_in_forms=array();
        $used_in_forms[]="adminhtml_customer";
        $used_in_forms[]="checkout_register";
        $used_in_forms[]="customer_account_create";
        $used_in_forms[]="customer_account_edit";
        $used_in_forms[]="adminhtml_checkout";
        $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute('customer', 'subscribedtags')
            ->setData('used_in_forms', [$used_in_forms])
            ->setData("is_used_for_customer_segment", true)
            ->setData("is_user_defined", 1)
            ->save();
        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```

Also a smaller test in Setup/Recurring.php:

```
<?php
namespace Wizbusiness\CustomerSubscriptions\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;

class Recurring implements InstallSchemaInterface {

    protected $logger;

    public function __construct(
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $loggerInterface
    ) {
        $this->logger = $loggerInterface;
    }

    public function install( SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context ) {
        touch("<path here>/recurring.txt");
        $this->logger->debug('This is running');
    }
}
```

If anybody knows what's up, please help me!

Comment: Just in case it helps someone: my issue was that I was using `class InstallSchema` in `InstallData.php` instead of `class InstallData`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Install scripts only run when the module is initially installed. To have it run again, you need to remove that module's row from the `setup_module` table with a query like below:

`DELETE FROM setup_module WHERE module=Module_Name`

Comment: Maked as the answer even tough it wasn't the solution to my problem as this is the most common trouble seen.

Answer (score 3):

Same problem, I found the problem will appear when the **`module` name** have **two or more capital letters**, like `Vendor\CapitalModule`. I had set the folder name capitalization, namespace and class name is right too, but the Setup scripts still never run. Strange problem OTZ

I solved the problem by changing the **module name** to **only one capital letter**, like changing  `Vendor\CapitalModule` to `Vendor\Capitalmodule`, then the Setup InstallSchema scripts will run.

Answer (score 2):

I've finally found a solution. I renamed the module folder to match it's name(capitalization included) and now the scripts are running as they should.

Comment: For me, this has the solution.

Answer (score 1):

i found that i was missing setup_version in etc/module.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
<module name="Name_ModuleName" setup_version="0.0.1">
</module>
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's see this: https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/magento-2-how-to-create-sql-setup-script.html, do not do it yourself. I think you should coppy the names, paths, do not write by hand

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same issue in my custom module. The issue was not the updated namespace of InstallSchema class.

I updated and it works

namespace Customvendorname\CustomModuleName\Setup;