# Magento 2.2: InstallData script never called even though no entry in setup_module

Tags: magento2, setup-script, setup-upgrade

Hello I have created a module in accordance to the tutorial at [Magento Docs](http://devdocs.magento.com/videos/fundamentals/add-new-product-attribute/)

My InstallData class looks like this:

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

 namespace Learning\ClothingMaterial\Setup;

 use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
 use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
 use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

 /**
 * @codeCoverageIgnore
 */
 class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
 {
     /**
      * Eav setup factory
      * @var EavSetupFactory
      */
     private $eavSetupFactory;

     /**
      * Init
      * @param CategorySetupFactory $categorySetupFactory
      */
     public function __construct(\Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
     {
        $timestamp = time();
        $myfile = fopen("install_log.txt", "a") or die("Unable to open file!");
        fwrite($myfile, $timestamp . " - Install construct start\n");
        fclose($myfile);
         $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
     }

     /**
      * {@inheritdoc}
      * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CyclomaticComplexity)
      * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveMethodLength)
      * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.NPathComplexity)
      */
     public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
     {
        $timestamp = time();
        $myfile = fopen("install_log.txt", "a") or die("Unable to open file!");
        fwrite($myfile, $timestamp . " - Install start\n");
        fclose($myfile);
         $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create();
         $eavSetup->addAttribute(
             \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
             'clothing_material',
             [
                 'group' => 'General',
                 'type' => 'varchar',
                 'label' => 'Clothing Material',
                 'input' => 'select',
                 'source' => 'Learning\ClothingMaterial\Model\Attribute\Source\Material',
                 'frontend' => 'Learning\ClothingMaterial\Model\Attribute\Frontend\Material',
                 'backend' => 'Learning\ClothingMaterial\Model\Attribute\Backend\Material',
                 'required' => false,
                 'sort_order' => 50,
                 'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
                 'is_used_in_grid' => false,
                 'is_visible_in_grid' => false,
                 'is_filterable_in_grid' => false,
                 'visible' => true,
                 'is_html_allowed_on_front' => true,
                 'visible_on_front' => true
             ]
         );
     }
 }
```

As you can see I added some write to file operations in order to check whether the class is actually called. The file never gets created. So the constructor and install method have never been called.

I already deleted the corresponding entry in the setup_module table and cleared caches, but it still dosen't get called when "php magento setup:upgrade" is executed.

What can be the reason?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Magento2: Setup Script not loaded](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/132052/magento2-setup-script-not-loaded)

Answer (score 0):

This problem was solved in this other thread: [Magento2: Setup Script not loaded](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/132052/magento2-setup-script-not-loaded)

My particular problem was that I had more than one capital letters .. and the name of the folder wasn't the same of the module.